# Google Play Services asks to “update” back to 9.0.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

Why i ask, on every solution i jsut have information that apply plugin on bottom, but i have this, but this not work on my side. I try to do this on 5 hours. Im got error after trying to implement google maps on my application. Maybe i miss something in code? I dont know where is problem, so please guys look at code, maybe you will have any idea whats wrong. Thanks fro advice.

This is error:

```
   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.



 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.andrzej.rolki.wroclawnarolkach"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` line from `dependencies` block. You wrote it twice.